# How to setup c# application and attach Mongodb Database

Tags: database, installation

I've made a C# application with MongoDB. I'm using "inno setup compiler" to build a setup. Everytime I launch my  App I must launch the MongoDB server (mongod.exe). Is there any way to attach the database in the setup, especially MongoDB?
I need to execute my application with one click without launching the MongoDB server.

[image]